# Селект для раскрытия блока

Tags: input, html-select

Имеется скрипт:

```js
<script>
<!--
function ChangeGenerate(val)
{
    if(val)
    {
        document.getElementById("sof_choose_login").style.display='none';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("sof_choose_login").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("NEW_GENERATE_N").checked = true;
    }

    try{document.order_reg_form.NEW_LOGIN.focus();}catch(e){}
}
//-->
</script>
```

Он отвечает за скрытие/раскрытие блока, вот код блока:

```html
<div id="sof_choose_login">
Test txt
</div>
```

Срабатывает, когда кликом ставим радиокнопку:

```html
<input type="radio" id="NEW_GENERATE_N" name="NEW_GENERATE" value="N" onclick="ChangeGenerate(false)">
```

Но, я хочу раскрывать скрытый блок не при клике по input, а через выбор в селект:

```html
  <select id="sof_choose_login" onchange="ChangeGenerate();">
   <option value="1">Option #1</option>
   <option value="2">Option #2</option>
  </select>
```

Пытался сделать следующим образом:

```js
function ChangeGenerate()
{
 alert(sof_choose_login.selectedIndex);
}
```

Но, не срабатывает и в консоли вижу ошибки. Пожалуйста подскажите, что не так делаю, видимо логику недовожу!

Спасибо.

Comment: Вы хотите чтоб при выборе одного из селекта появлялся еще какой то текст где то?

Comment: Да, верно. Выбрав одно значение из селекта, чтобы блок в <div> раскрывался становясь доступным для пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий пример, но вам нужно какая то логика скорее привязка value к data аттрибуту блока

```js
document.getElementById("sof_choose_login").addEventListener("change", (e)=>{
  ChangeGenerate(e)
})
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".select")
function ChangeGenerate(event){
  elements.forEach(e=>{
    e.style.display = "none"
  })
  elements[event.target.value-1].style.display="flex"
}
```

```css
.select{
display: none;
color: red;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<select id="sof_choose_login">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
   <option value="1">Option #1</option>
   <option value="2">Option #2</option>
  </select>
  
  
  <div class="select select1">Select 1</div>
  <div class="select select2">Select 2</div>
```

**UPD** Если должен быть какой то пункт выбран по умолчанию
Это простой пример, можно посторить логику

```js
document.getElementById("sof_choose_login").addEventListener("change", (e)=>{
  ChangeGenerate(e)
})

let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".select")

function ChangeGenerate(event){
  elements.forEach(e=>{
    e.style.display = "none"
  })
  elements[event.target.value-1].style.display="flex"
}


// При загрузке страницы получить значение активного элемента и показать соотвествующий div 
elements[document.getElementById("sof_choose_login").value-1].style.display = "flex"
```

```css
.select{
display: none;
color: red;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<select id="sof_choose_login">
   <option value="1">Option #1</option>
   <option value="2">Option #2</option>
  </select>
  
  
  <div class="select select1">Select 1</div>
  <div class="select select2">Select 2</div>
```

Comment: Получается, что по умолчанию два блока будут закрыты:

  <div class="select select1">Select 1</div>
  <div class="select select2">Select 2</div>

При выборе первого из селекта, второй остается закрытый (что логично). При выборе второго с селекта, тоже логично закрывать первый блок. Но, у меня получается, что первый блок служит основанием второго.

Comment: @Nicolo обновил, я в первом случае специально сделал пустой выбор, чтоб не весел всегда открытый первый в списке селект, добавил вариант как изначально у вас было только с двумя

Comment: Хотя в таком примере достаточно было добавить css `.select1{display: flex}`

Comment: Спасибо, попробую и отпишу!

Comment: Добрый день! Выдает ошибку: http://joxi.ru/BA0EVqvupeloyr

Comment: В ошибке написано что переменная уже существует с имением elements, переназовите.

Comment: А первая ошибка это для какого элемента? Вы дождались загрузки ДОМ перед вызовом функции?

Comment: Спасибо, еще раз! Но, я решил такой вариант использовать - вроде работает. Публикую здесь, вдруг пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

Greg - спасибо за помощь!

Я, нашел еще решение, возможно кому поможет как и мне сейчас:

```html
  <select id="test" name="form_select">
   <option value="0">No</option>
   <option value ="1" onClick"showDiv()">Yes</option>
</select>
<div id="hidden_div" style="display: none;">Hello hidden content</div>
<script>
var select = document.getElementById('test'),
onChange = function(event) {
  var shown = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 1;

    document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = shown ? 'block' : 'none';
};

if (select.addEventListener) {
    select.addEventListener('change', onChange, false);
} else {
  select.attachEvent('onchange', function() {
    onChange.apply(select, arguments);
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: А вы разобрались в коде? если вы уберете ` onClick"showDiv()"` и условие `if (select.addEventListener) {... ` оставите только `select.addEventListener('change', onChange, false);` то ничего не поменяется, почему?

Comment: `if (select.addEventListener) ` это условие проверяет поддерживает ли браузер DOM level 2 API, что будет всегда true так как нет уже браузеров которые не поддерживают [СПИСОК](https://caniuse.com/?search=addEventListener) этот код идет годами как мусорный от ответа к ответу. В строке `<option value ="1" onClick"showDiv()">Yes</option>` запись onClick с ошибкой и соотвественно строка вообще ничего не делает а просто плодит мусор в коде.